# Why does using alert in Shopify cart/add API only add product in cart for firefox browser?

Tags: php, jquery, firefox, shopify

I want to add a product in cart page of my Shopify website.I am using Shopify cart/add.js API for adding a product in cart.It's working in Google Chrome browse.But for Firefox it's not working.How can i do it in Mozilla Firefox using same API and withot using alert box?

I am performing event on click of Add to cart button

```
<button class="btn" id="add_raffle">
  <span id="AddToCartText-product-template">Add to cart</span>
</button>
```

Form to post

```
<form action="/cart/add" id="raffle_prod">
<input type = "hidden" name="id" value = "13597453582389" id="raffle_variant">
<input type = "hidden" name="quantity" value = "1" > 
<input type="submit" style="display:none" id="raffle_submit">
```

Jquery Code

```
$('#add_raffle').click(function(event){
    var FIREFOX = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (FIREFOX) {
         $('#raffle_submit').trigger("click");
         alert('Raffle tickets added. Thanks!');
    } else {
        var dataString = $('#raffle_variant').serialize();
        jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', dataString);
        alert('Raffle tickets added. Thanks!');
    }
});
```

This code is working for Google chrome.

But for Firefox following code is not working.I need to post a form and use alert after request then product is adding in cart.

I want to avoid alert and want to use same api code as i do for google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `if` statement in your jQuery code.

Fixed:

```
    $('#add_raffle').click(function(event){
    var dataString = $('#raffle_variant').serialize()
    jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', dataString)});
```

Comment: I use the statement if because that code was not working in firefox.